# Am I licensing this code correctly?

Tags: licensing, license

I am using icons from [here](https://github.com/tabler/tabler-icons) for my web project.
This is the file I used for one of the icons:

```
<!--
This file was licenced under the following license:

MIT License

Copyright (c) 2020 Paweł Kuna

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
SOFTWARE.
-->

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-messages" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
  <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
  <path d="M21 14l-3 -3h-7a1 1 0 0 1 -1 -1v-6a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h9a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v10" />
  <path d="M14 15v2a1 1 0 0 1 -1 1h-7l-3 3v-10a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h2" />
</svg>
```

My question is: Is this a good place to put the license? Is there a better way to place this license in my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a legal viewpoint, it is entirely correct to have the license text in the file that is being licensed itself. If you received the file like that, then that is another reason to keep the license text there.

If you have a readme file in your project where you state something about the license of the project, you could add a short paragraph there that you are using these icons and that they are under the MIT license. This is not a requirement and more of an acknowledgement of the work of others than anything else.